# Woocommerce 404 page instead of admin orders list page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, http-status-code-404, orders

I have a big problem on my Woocommerce admin panel, when I try opening the following URL: 
 `wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=shop_order`

Wordpress redirects automatically to 404 error page.
Only this page doesn't work. It is strange because yesterday was ok.

I replaced all Wordpress and Woocommerce files to original and deactivated all others plugins. It didn't help.

Comment: Are you familiar with the `.htaccess` file?  You should find it in the root of your website.  As a trial and error exercise, make a copy of your `.htaccess` file onto your computer.  Then remove it from your website.  Does this solve the problem?  If this does solve the problem, paste the code, in the `.htaccess` into your question, and hopefully one of us will be able to advise on the 'offending' code.

Comment: I removed .htaccess and Wordpress created new. Unfortunately it didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. I fixed problem.
One order had wrong meta in database because I tested different payment plugin few days ago (during few hours) and meantime one customer made order.
After plugin change this meta value made conflict with new payment plugin. 
I removed this meta value in phpMyAdmin and now works perfect.

Comment: Can you explain how you fixed this? I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem - after a lot of debugging I discovered that the meta problem was in wp_postmeta where meta_key='_transaction_id'. For some reason, the meta_value was a serialised WC_Order object and this resulted in some sort of infinite loop.

Solution was to do something like:

delete from wp_postmeta where meta_key = '_transaction_id' and meta_value like '%WC_Order%';

I have no idea how it made it in there in the first place, though!

Comment: In my case wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=product page showing 404. I removed blank transaction_id

delete from wp_postmeta where meta_key = '_transaction_id' and meta_value = '';